# Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in my flutter app while fetching datafrom api

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, backend

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:the_kitchen/constants/global_variables.dart';
import 'package:the_kitchen/models/category.model.dart';
import 'package:the_kitchen/service/category.service.dart';

class CategoryListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CategoryListScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _CategoryListScreenState createState() => _CategoryListScreenState();
}

class _CategoryListScreenState extends State<CategoryListScreen> {
  // List to store fetched categories
  List<Category> categories = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchCategories();
  }

  // Fetch all categories
  void fetchCategories() async {
    final fetchedCategories = await CategoryService.fetchAllCategories();
    setState(() {
      categories = fetchedCategories.cast<Category>();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: GlobalVariables.secondaryColor,
        title: const Text('Category Management'),
      ),
      body: CategoryList(categories),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Category> categories;

  const CategoryList(this.categories);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: categories.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final category = categories[index];
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(category.categoryName,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.black
          )
          ),
          subtitle: Text(category.categoryGujaratiName),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'dart:convert';
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
import 'package:the_kitchen/models/category.model.dart';

class CategoryService {
  static const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/categories/findall';

  // Create a new category
  static Future<Category> createCategory(String categoryName, String categoryGujaratiName) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(apiUrl),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: jsonEncode({
        'categoryName': categoryName,
        'categoryGujaratiName': categoryGujaratiName,
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return Category(
        id: responseData['_id'],
        categoryName: responseData['categoryName'],
        categoryGujaratiName: responseData['categoryGujaratiName'],
      );
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to create category');
    }
  }

  // Fetch all categories
  static Future<List<Category>> fetchAllCategories() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrl));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List<dynamic> responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return responseData.map((item) {
        return Category(
          id: item['_id'],
          categoryName: item['categoryName'],
          categoryGujaratiName: item['categoryGujaratiName'],
        );
      }).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch categories');
    }
  }

  // Implement methods to fetch by ID, update, and delete categories if needed
}
```

Basically I am trying to fetch data from my MongoDB and show it to flutter app but I am getting this error mentioned above. I tested API with Postman and its working well but I don't know whats problem with this code. So can someone help me with this?

I just want to show it to my flutter app screen nothing more than that.

Comment: You may be missing a null check.

Comment: Add nullable to your Category class.

class Category {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? gujaratiName;

  Category({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.gujaratiName,
  });
}

Comment: Use debugging tool and brake point is better :-)

Comment: That's because you want a String type but your data give a null value. Try to add null safety like @WaiHanKo said.